# The theme in manifest.xml

Tags: android, manifest

I change

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

But why it can not change orientation?
If use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen", it can change orientation.
But if change to another one, it can't.
I try it in Android 2.3.4.
But in Android 4.0.2, it works success on change orientation.
Why and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

to each activity you need.